# parsing email attachments in php

Tags: php, base64, explode, email-attachments

I have a .forward.postix that is piping incoming emails to a shell account, and consequently to a PHP script that parses the emails - awesome.

As of now, and based on everything I've seen online, I'm using the `explode('From: ', $email);` approach to split everything down into the vars I need for my database.

Enter attachments! Using the same approach, I'm doing this to pull out a jpg attachment - but it appears not every email client formats the raw source the same way and it's causing some headaches!

```
$contentType1 = explode('Content-type: image/jpg;', $email); //start ContentType
$contentType2 = explode("--Boundary_", $contentType1[1]); //end ContentType

$jpg1 = explode("\n\n", $contentType2[0]); //double return starts base64 blob
$jpg2 = explode("\n\n", $jpg1[1]); //double return marks end of base64 blob

$image = base64_decode($jpg2[0]); //decode base64 blob into jpg raw
```

**Here's my issue:**
Not all mail clients - like GMail for example - list an attachment as `'Content-type: image/jpg'`. GMail puts in `'Content-Type: IMAGE/JPEG'` and sometimes sends it as `'Content-Type: image/jpeg'`! Which don't match my explode...

**My Question:** Does someone know a better way of finding the bounds of a base64 blob? or maybe a case-insensitive way of exploding the `'Content-Type:'` so I can then try against `image/jpg` or `image-jpeg` to see what matches?

Comment: On an additional note: I'd advise you to use Regex to match your header statements instead of explode.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP builtin IMAP function? I have successfully implemented a solution with it in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split your string using `preg_split()`.  Maybe something like this

```
$pattern = '#content-type: image/jpe?g#i';
$split_array = preg_split($pattern, $email);
```

Comment: See, i KNEW there would be a way of writing a pattern that would solve all my problems - but those patterns make NO sense to me and I cannot for the life of me find a "dictionary" of what does what. I'm guessing the `e?` makes the e optional, and the `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive? Thank you friend!

Comment: @JoelHackney Yes the `?` indicates that there can be 0 or 1 or the preceding pattern component.  The pattern modifier `i` makes the match case insensitive as you guessed.

Comment: @JoelHackney Please note my revised answer.  I just noticed that I made the search for `image.jpe?g` (like a filename) and not `image/jpe?g` (content type)

Comment: Yeah i was just about to say I couldn't get the previous pattern to work - with your revision, it works perfectly!